# Rspec no route matches polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test my polymorphic comments create action but I always get no route matches error in rspec.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Your comment was successfully posted."
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

Rspec

```
describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      before do
        @project = FactoryGirl.create(:project)
        @comment_attr = FactoryGirl.build(:comment).attributes
      end

      it "creates a new comment" do
        expect{
          post :create, params: { project_id: @project, comment: @comment_attr }
        }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
```

I am using this approach for testing create action in my another controllers and there is everything good, but here from some reason is throws error. I think my error is in line where I pass params to post create action but I do not see error.

UPDATE

```
 resources :projects do
    resources :comments, module: :projects
    resources :tasks do
      resources :comments, module: :tasks
    end
  end
```

UPDATE 2

> Failure/Error: post :create, params: { project_id: @project,
>   commentable: @project, comment: @comment_attr }
>
> ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>   No route matches {:action=>"create", :comment=>{"id"=>nil, "commentable_type"=>nil, "commentable_id"=>nil, "user_id"=>nil,
>   "body"=>"MyText", "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil,
>   "attachment"=>nil}, :commentable=>#, :controller=>"comments", :project_id=>#}

Comment: What is setting `@commentable` in your controller?  And seeing `routes.rb` would help as well, in addition to the rest of the test file you've excerpted.

Comment: @JimVanFleet updated my question with routes. Commentable is project or task, but I am trying to test case when commentable is project.

Comment: I understand your intent, but `@commentable` is `nil` based on what we see above.  Is it a helper in `ApplicationController`?  Are you getting 404s in your test logs or 500s?

Comment: Where is the error? Why would you have a question about an error and not post the error? I understand the basic error but post some portion of the actual error because "no route matches error" is very vague. `No route matches {:controller => "comments", :action => "create"}` is a very different error than `No route matches {:controller => "unicorns", :action => "rainbows"}` or `No route matches [POST] /projects/:project_id/comments`

Comment: @engineersmnky I updated question with full error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your controller namespace does not match the routes you define. The controller is defined to not be nested (`CommentsController`) whereas the corresponding routes are nested and inside a module `projects` as well. Nesting the routes will have no influence on the controller ActionDispatch is looking for. But defining a module for the route will lead to rails expecting a controller inside the module namespace. In your case that would be `Projects::CommentsController` and `Tasks::CommentsController`. Please see ["2.6 Controller Namespaces and Routing" of "Rails Routing from the Outside In"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for further details.

I added your routes to a brand new rails project and ran `rails routes`. The output is:

```
                             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
     project_comments GET    /projects/:project_id/comments(.:format)  projects/comments#index
                      POST   /projects/:project_id/comments(.:format)  projects/comments#create
                      ...
```

You can therefor either remove the module definition from your routes

```
resources :projects do
  resources :comments
  resources :tasks do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

or nest the controllers inside in a project/task namespace. Given that you want polymorphism for your comments, I would advise using the first option.